# How to check specific value in JSONArray?

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I have a little problem with looping in Swift 3. I have one JSONArray and one JSONObject like below :

dataReqList [Any] :

```
[{
bezeich = "MORE SALT";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 1;
}, {
bezeich = "MORE SWEET";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 2;
}, {
bezeich = "MORE PEPPER";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 3;
}, {
bezeich = "MORE CHILLI";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 4;
}, {
bezeich = COLD;
grpnr = 0;
nr = 5;
}, {
bezeich = HOT;
grpnr = 0;
nr = 6;
}, {
bezeich = SMALL;
grpnr = 0;
nr = 7;
}, {
bezeich = LARGE;
grpnr = 0;
nr = 8;
}, {
bezeich = "MEDIUM COOKED";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 9;
}, {
bezeich = "WELL DONE";
grpnr = 0;
nr = 10;
}]
```

currArticle [Anyhashable: Any] :

```
Optional([AnyHashable("bezeich"): Fresh and Green Salad, 
        AnyHashable("special-request"): ["MORE PEPPER", "COLD", "HOT"]])
```

I want to know, how to print the key `bezeich` in array , if the JSONArray have same `String` with `special-request` in JSONObject. I've try this but its not working :

```
for i in 0..<dataReqList.count {
        if ( ((dataReqList[i] as? [AnyHashable: Any])? ["bezeich"] as! String) == (("\(currArticle?["special-request"]!)") as String) ) {
            print (dataReqList[i])
        }
```

Any answer and suggest will help for me. Thanks in advance

EDIT : 
I'm new in Swift. I have read [THIS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) before but its still not work.

Comment: Please do a basic search before posting a question.

Comment: @shallowThought sorry Mr. Expert , see my edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key `special-request` with `currArticle` Dictionary having `Array` of String as value so you can not directly compare it with string, you can use filter for that like this.

```
var filterArray = [[String:Any]]() 
if let dataArray = dataReqList as? [[String:Any]],
   let specialRequestArray = currArticle["special-request"] as? [String] {

     filterArray = dataArray.filter { specialRequestArray.contains($0["bezeich"] as? String ?? "") }
     print(filterArray)
}
```

Comment: its not working. the print line is never execute. but i understand the meaning of your block code. I'll try to modify. thanks

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta If what you show in question is correct then this should work perfectly

Comment: really sorry i'm new in swift. In android studio, JSON output look like normal not like in xcode (with optional, other symbol or etc)

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta Then show us that original JSON instead of console log of Xcode

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta It happens mate :)